# Lemmatization/stemming libraries for Java?

Tags: library, java

I'm currently creating a search engine in Java. I use Apache Lucene's analyzers. I would like to stem my documents but I can't choose a library because I don't know what the best is. I've read about Lucene Snowball, Porter Stemmer, Lucene's Morfologik Analyzer and many others. Almost all are old, I'm not sure if they are deprecated, or if there are better libraries. My Apache Lucene is version 8.0. Can you suggest me a good one?